# PHP: Declare the type of an argument as Class (like Java)

Tags: php, function, class, type-hinting, type-declaration

We can specify the type of an argument in java as `Class` or `Class<?>` or `Class<SomeClass>` or `Class<? extends SomeClass>`. Also, we know [PHP has added type declaration capability (were also known as type hints in PHP 5)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). So is a way to declare the type of an argument of a `function` as `Class` (like Java) in PHP?

For example (in PHP):

```
function f(Class<string> $clazz) { ... }  // ???
```

Comment: Are you wanting a generic "class" type or a specific class?

Comment: @Scuzzy. Both. But if one is not possible, I want another. Each has its own importance.

Comment: Looks like this may be relevant: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics -- to my knowledge PHP doesn't offer this type of functionality that you're after at present. You could just omit the type declaration, it's not ideal but doing that will allow you to have different instances where some use `string`, some use `FooClass` and so on

Answer (score 2):

As you said, this is referred to as [type hinting](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in PHP.

Example from the PHP docs:

```
<?php
// An example class
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * A test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an object of type OtherClass
     */
    public function test(OtherClass $otherclass) {
        echo $otherclass->var;
    }


    /**
     * Another test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an array
     */
    public function test_array(array $input_array) {
        print_r($input_array);
    }

    /**
     * First parameter must be iterator
     */
    public function test_interface(Traversable $iterator) {
        echo get_class($iterator);
    }

    /**
     * First parameter must be callable
     */
    public function test_callable(callable $callback, $data) {
        call_user_func($callback, $data);
    }
}

// Another example class
class OtherClass {
    public $var = 'Hello World';
}
?>
```

The part that really matters in your question is this function, where `OtherClass` is specifying that the argument must be an instance of `OtherClass`, otherwise, PHP will throw an error.

```
<?php
    /**
     * A test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an object of type OtherClass
     */
    public function test(OtherClass $otherclass) {
        echo $otherclass->var;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't want a variable (argument) with type of `OtherClass`! I want an argument with type of **the class of `OtherClass`**; that can be declared in Java such: `Class<OtherClass> var`.